# ways to loop through a json with next-intl

Tags: next.js, internationalization, i18next

**Hello,**

I need help translating my site and I can't find a way to automate the translation by checking the key and value.

***Example en.json and es.json:***

```
`en.json...
"Navigation": [
    {
      "path": "/",
      "text": "Home"
    },
    {
      "path": "/contact",
      "text": "Contact"      
    }
],`

`es.json
"Navigation": [
    {
      "path": "/",
      "text": "Inicio"
    },
    {
      "path": "/contact",
      "text": "Contacto"      
    }
],`
```

NavBar.tsx...

```
`import { useTranslations } from "next-intl";

const translate = useTranslations("Navigation")

translate.map((nav) => console.log(nav.path)) `
```

Is there a way to loop through the json without having to do it line by line?

Thanskkkk :)

I made the map and it didn't work

**I expected:**

Home
Contact

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need some links inside your navigation section. Maybe you could try something like this:

1. create linkElements.js:

   export const linkElements = [
   {
   children:"home",
   href:"/",
   },
   {
   children:"contact",
   href:"/contact",
   },
   ]
2. create Links.js :

   "use client"

   import Link from "next-intl/link"
   import {useTranslations} from 'next-intl';

   export default function Links({ children, href}) {
   const t = useTranslations("Navigation")

   ```
    return (
        <Link
            href={href}    
        >
            {t(children)}
        </Link>
    )
   ```

   }

Now your link title is translated and you can map it in your Navigation.js:

```
<ul>
    {LinkElements.map((element, index) => (
       <Links key={index} {...element} />
    ))}
  </ul>
```

I hope this helps!